# Why Ionic Native Device Plugin is not working in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 Angular app , and using Ionic Native Device plugin but it is not working as expected or shown in their documentation ? any 
solution how to use this plugin ?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: same issue `Native: tried calling Device.model, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator`

Comment: i have already install cordova but error shown cordova is not available

Comment: It is simple thing,we are run app on browser that's why it's give warning message.cordova act as bridge between web app to native app.when app run on any emulator or devices at that time cordova plugin used,when app run on broswer ,then cordova plugin not used.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple thing,we are run app on browser that's why it's give warning message.cordova act as bridge between web app to native app.when app run on any emulator or devices at that time cordova plugin used,when app run on broswer ,then cordova plugin not used